# How to draw Poisson density curve in R?

Tags: r

I need to show that the amount of events in Poisson process are distributed by Poisson distribution with parameter lambda * t.
Here is the Poisson process generator:

```
 ppGen <- function(lambda, maxTime){
      taos <- taosGen(lambda, maxTime)
      pp <- NULL
      for(i in 1:maxTime){
        pp[i] <- sum(taos <= i)
      }
      return(pp)
    }
```

Here I try to replicate the process 1000 times and vectorisee the total occurrences in each realisation:

```
 d <- ppGen(0.5,100)
    tail(d,n=1)
    reps <- 1000
    x1 <- replicate(reps, tail(ppGen(0.5,100), n=1))
    hist(x1)
```

Here is the histogram:

[image]

Here I am trying to draw a theoretical Poisson density curve with parameter lambda * t:

```
xfit<-seq(1,100,length=100)
yfit<-dpois(xfit,lambda = 0.5*100)

lines(xfit,yfit)
```

But the curve doesn't appear anywhere near the histogram. Can anyone suggest on the right way to do this?

Comment: You do not appear to provide the definition of the `taosGen()` function.

Comment: @IanCampbell taosGen generated the intervals between occurrences of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `curve` like below

```
x <- rpois(1000, 0.5 * 100)
dp <- function(x, lbd = 0.5 * 100) dpois(x, lambda = lbd)
curve(dp, 0, 100)
hist(x, freq = FALSE, add = TRUE)
```

[image]